# How to select only one checkbox in dynamic form in angular 8

Tags: typescript, angular8, dynamicform

I have a dynamic form which is producing 8 different checkboxes according to the API response. Now I want the user to be able to select only 1 check box at a time. If the user wants to select a different checkbox he first has to deselect the selected checkbox. Please refer to the code below.

```
<ng-container *ngIf="field.inputType==='group';else singleCase">
    <p class="font20" *ngIf="field.label">{{'label.' + field.name | translate}}</p>
    <div class="row purFin table-responsive pb-3 mb-2 mt-4">
      <div class="col-12">
        <ng-container [formArrayName]="field.name"
          *ngFor="let item of group.controls[field.name].controls; let i = index">
          <input type="checkbox" class="hidden" (click)="preventCheck($event)" (change)="onChange($event)" [formControlName]="i"
            [name]="field.name + i+1" [id]="field.name + i+1">
          <label class="btn-outline-secondary mr-3 mt-1 but" [for]="field.name + i+1">
            {{field.options[i].value}}
          </label>
        </ng-container>
        <div class="col-12">
          <span *ngIf="'sub_text.' + field.name | translate"
            class="font12">{{'sub_text.' + field.name | translate}}</span>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div *ngIf="group.get(field.name).invalid && (group.get(field.name).dirty || group.get(field.name).touched)"
      class="error-msg">
      <ng-container *ngFor="let validation of field.validations">
        <div *ngIf="group.get(field.name).hasError(validation.name)">{{validation.message}}</div>
      </ng-container>
    </div>
  </ng-container>
```

Comment: Can you please create a small demo on stackblitz.com?

Comment: Isn't input with type `radio` fits your requirements?

Answer (score 3):

It can be done in multiple ways, with reacting on change/click event and saving the name of checked/clicked element. 
Consider below as an example, maybe it's not the most elegant solution, but you can implement logic in many ways actually:
[HTML]

```js
export class YourComponentClass  {
  isChecked;
  isCheckedName;
  checkboxData = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];
  onChange(e){       
    this.isChecked = !this.isChecked;
    this.isCheckedName = e.target.name;
  }
}
```

```html
<div *ngFor="let name of checkboxData">
<input type="checkbox" [name]="name" (change)="onChange($event)" [disabled]="isChecked && (isCheckedName!=name)"> {{'Checkbox ' + name}}
 </div>
```

online: [you can check it on stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xy9mag)

And in case you don't need much from $event, better to pass to component only data that you need,so you may change to onChange($event.target.name) in html, and in ts code this.isCheckedName = e; accordingly.

Good luck ;)

Answer (score 2):

If you are using material/cdk in your app there is an easy to implement solution involving `SelectionModel` that works well with Reactive Forms/FormBuilder.

In your component declare:

```
selection = new SelectionModel<any>(false, []);
```

Then in your template/html:

```
  <tr *ngFor="let item of formArray['controls']; let i = index;" [formGroupName]="i" class="tr-body-format">
        <td class="td-format">
             <mat-checkbox formControlName="selected" (change)="$event ? 
                  selection.toggle(i) : null" [checked]="selection.isSelected(i)">
             </mat-checkbox>
         </td>
```